# How to use MarkdownView android library to loop through an unordered list

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

With the above library and this code below, this is what I get

code

```
 String description="";
        String markdown = "*";
        for (JsonElement e:sl.get("description").getAsJsonArray()){
            if(!e.getAsString().trim().isEmpty() && CharMatcher.javaUpperCase().or(CharMatcher.javaLetter().negate()).matchesAllOf(e.getAsString().trim())) {
                SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(e.getAsString());
                s1.setSpan(new BulletSpan(20), 1, e.getAsString().length(), 0);
                description +=s1 + "\n\n";
            }else if(!e.getAsString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(e.getAsString());
                s1.setSpan(new BulletSpan(20), 1, e.getAsString().length(), 0);
                description += markdown+ s1 + "\n\n";

            }



        }

        viewHolder.body.setMarkDownText(description);
```

This is the output

[image]

What can I do to ensure that the dot appears for all the other list items as in the first one.?

This is the output I need

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like appending SpannableString to String for description is causing problem.

Make a array of SpannableString for storing all description from Json element and then at the end concat all description and set it to text view. Refer pseudo 
 code below

```
SpannableString[] descriptionArray = new SpannableString[YourJsonArray.length];

// Read individual description in loop and add them to array here.

//Now outside the for loop concat and set all description
viewHolder.body.setMarkDownText(TextUtils.concat(descriptionArray));
```

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: But the description is an array of list elements. So what I want is to bullet the lists

Comment: You can not mix SpannableString and String. Make an array of SpannableString for description list array and then concat and set it to body using TextUtils.concat